# Long running WCF operation - increasing receiveTimeout in basicHttpBinding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

Our application exposes an IIS-hosted WCF service called by a client's SOA middleware (i think it's the Oracle SOA Suite, if that matters). The operation imports a raw data file to our db.

The body of the service method is

```
public void ImportAssenze(XmlElement import)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => LongRunningProcess());
    }
```

The process is run in another task because some time ago, working on other operations inside this service, other client-side timeout problems emerged, so I now use this pattern for all operations; before that, it was simply a call to `LongRunningProcess()`.
 So right now the actual web service call lasts ~2 seconds (I also see it in `soapUI`) and from then the import operation goes on in the background.

(*side question:because it was agreed that there was no need for the client to be notified via callback when the operation completed, the method returns void.
So a client has no visibility of the async nature of the operation from the wsdl: is this bad design?*)

The problem is that for certain source files the process exceeds the 10 minutes inactivity timeout, so the `Session_End` event is fired and some internal state of my process gets irremediably corrupted. I expect this particular file to be kind of a "worst case", the average runtime should be ~5 minutes, but other operations may incur in the same problem in the future, so this needs to be solved.

As for the service configuration, the web.config had nothing written, so the service ran with the `basicHttpBinding` binding with all the defaults. The contract is

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = ProcessiHelper.Namespace)]
public interface IProcessi_7044852
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ImportAssenze(XmlElement import);
}
```

I can't find the link anymore, but an answered question here suggested increasing the `inactivityTimeout` on `reliableSession` and the `receiveTimeout` on the `binding` (another place that mentions it is [here](http://nogeekhere.blogspot.it/2009/04/why-will-wcf-client-be-disconnected.html))

```
    <binding name="Processi_7044852Binding" receiveTimeout="00:00:30">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:30"/>
    </binding>
```

But `reliableSession` isn't available with `basicHttpBinding`. I tried increasing the second one only, so I created a `service` node

```
    <services>
  <service name="Archimede.HRSuite.TurniArc.Processi_7044852" behaviorConfiguration="">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Processi_7044852Binding" contract="Archimede.HRSuite.TurniArc.IProcessi_7044852"/>
  </service>    
</services>
```

and a `binding` node with a 30 seconds timeout

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Processi_7044852Binding" receiveTimeout="00:00:30">
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

but I see nothing different; the session gets purged after ten minutes.
I also tried `receiveTimeout="infinite"` with no luck.

[This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a68ff12-c290-49fd-afda-733604ca5539/receivetimeout-working-with-nettcpbinding-but-not-with-basichttpbinding?forum=wcf) seems to match my problem, and the last reply by Marco Zhou (who seems to be inside the WCF team?) confirmed the strange behaviour, but with no further feedback.

Is there any work-around? I don't know if I can change the binding and force the client to sync its proxy. Besides, if I change the config to

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Processi_7044852Binding" receiveTimeout="00:00:30">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:30"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

together with `<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" [..]`, a call to the service in soapUI for some reason doesn't work, and the process doesn't even start, so I'm not sure yet how/if I could make that alternative work.

Thanks (and sorry for the long post!)

Comment: I don't think trying to increase the timeout values is the best approach. My approach would be to use a reliable queue and use a seperate process to process the items in the queue.

Comment: @WvanNoort Why is it not a good approach? Look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622634

Comment: @EduardoLion Look at the latest comments on your question. They mention the exact same posts i should have directed you to.

Comment: Tnx mate! I'll look!